# Refreshing vue app gives "Cannot GET /route" error in development and production, despite settings

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, page-refresh

I am using vue 2.6.10 and node v10.16.0 and express 4.17.1.

In my `vue.config.js` I do

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    outputDir : path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    devServer:{
        proxy:{
            '/*':{
                target:'http://localhost:4000'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my vue  `router.js` I have

```
const router =  new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
  //........
```

In my `app.js` for node, according to what I red online, I have

```
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
const staticFileMiddleware = express.static(path.join(__dirname,'quad-client')); 

const app = express();
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);
app.use(history({
    disableDotRule: true,
    verbose: true
}));
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);  

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public'))); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false})); 

app.use('/vesselperformance', require('./routes/vesselperformance'));
//more routes

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('server runs on port ', port);
});
```

If I do this, refreshing gives a `Cannot GET /route` error in development , and in production I cannot see the app when I go to `localhost:4000`

I have to edit node `app.js` like so (remove the `connect-history-api-fallback`-related code)

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public'))); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false})); 

app.use('/login', require('./routes/login'));
//more routes

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    //static folder
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public'))); 
    //handle SPA
    app.get(/.*/, (req, res)=>{
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
    });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('server runs on port ', port);
});
```

This will show the app in `localhost:4000`, but still has the same problem with refreshing in production and development.

What am I missing ? How can I fix the refreshing problem? Thanks.